# Specflow generated tests are not running at the command line

Tags: .net-core, specflow

I'm using the `calculator` example. I'm running .NET Core SDK 3.1, editing code in VS Code. The csproj is below.

Doing a `dotnet test` gives the result below. The `feature` file is code generated, but the test doesn't run.

```
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.

  ! AddTwoNumbers [159ms]

Test Run Successful.
```

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"> 

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup> 

  <ItemGroup>

    <PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.15.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="specflow.nunit" Version="3.1.97" />
    <PackageReference Include="specflow.tools.msbuild.generation" Version="3.1.97" />

  </ItemGroup> 

</Project>
```

Comment: Check the output pane  and select test from the drop down. What is the error? Is it registered?

Comment: Thanks @Dazed. The steps file was not generated. I'm using vs code. Do you know of a way to generate the steps file? From the cli or vscode? Or this can only be done from in Visual Studio proper?

Comment: I would go through this - https://specflow.org/documentation/SpecFlow-and-.NET-Core/. Make sure you only have 1 unit test provider.

Comment: Doug did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes! Thanks @Dazed. The messages from SpecFlow were challenging. A combination of versions and coding up the steps correctly.

Comment: Glad you got it resolved. SpecFlow can be temperamental at times but well worth it in the end.